# New to the Linux game, need help

Tags: software-recommendation

I am currently trying to convert my newly purchased laptop to an OS that is similar to Windows but without all of the other other headaches associated with it.

I plan on using the laptop for surfing and business purposes only, since I have my Playstation for my gaming purposes.

Can you please recommend an OS that would fit my needs?

Answer (score 8):

Three introductory statements:

- Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.
- [Ubuntu is an operating system!](http://www.ubuntu.com/)
- Ask Ubuntu is a site that supports Ubuntu users and developers.

With those in mind, any answer you get here is almost certainly going to be from somebody who uses Ubuntu, and they're probably going to suggest you try Ubuntu.

Ubuntu is a great OS but in the interest of balance I'd be irresponsible to blindly tell you to wipe your system and stick Ubuntu on and hope everything goes fine.

The main issue of any OS migration is the applications you use. Browsing is just fine but what "business purposes" are you talking about? Do you **need** to run certain software? Windows software is largely incompatible with other operating systems (although [there are workarounds](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine)).

I would definitely suggest you download Ubuntu and *try* it for a few hours. It's free to download. Burn it to a CD/USB or install it under Windows and restart the machine (there is help on [the download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download)). If it works well for you, you can look at doing a proper install and migrating your data over.

Answer (score 3):

Well since you are on a forum for [Ubuntu Linux](http://www.ubuntu.com/download) this will likely be your first answer. Ubuntu is a great distribution for people who are new to Linux, with very clear instructions on how to set your laptop up with Windows + Ubuntu or only Ubuntu. Simply go to the [download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download) and follow the instructions from there to get started!

Most beginner Linux distributions come with a large feature set such as web browser, office suite, and media players that you won't see included by default with Windows. Each distro also features an intuitive User Interface that should allow you to become comfortable with transitioning from windows fairly quickly. You are likely to find it even more intuitive than the Windows layout!

If Ubuntu is not to your liking you can try several Ubuntu-based distributions that use Ubuntu as a starting point, but will often have different default applications or user interfaces.

[Linux Mint](http://www.linuxmint.com/) - is a popular Ubuntu based distro that combines a different user interface with the default inclusion of many popular plugins and codec's such as Flash and mp3 support.

[Pinguy OS](http://pinguy-os.sourceforge.net/) - is a version of Ubuntu that includes tons of default applications to fit every users needs, and focuses on providing a enjoyable out-of-the-box experience for all users.

[Elementary OS](http://elementaryos.org/) - is a distribution based off of Ubuntu that emphasises a clean user interface with elimination of clutter and good-looking, simple applications. This distro is new in the game, but certainly one to watch.

And remember that you are more than welcome to try all or any of these distributions without affecting your laptop! Simply download the .iso, burn it to a CD, and restart your computer with it in the drive. When prompted, select "Try operating system" to give the distribution a test run before installing! If you decide you like it, you can run the installer from within the test run.

Comment: Also I know Linux Mint is moving towards Debian, but I thought I would mention it anyways.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? If it is a bad answer, an explaining comment would help avoid more of them in the future.

Comment: Don't worry too much about votes on stackexchange; sometimes they aren't logical. :)

Comment: Haha alright, well I won't fret about it too much then.